# Espresso - click on textview(button)

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to perform click on textview ( this textview is under a linear layout), but it is gives below mentioned error. Tried Espresso.onData also but it raise some other error. So How to use  Espresso.onData in this case?

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: logout:id/Profile_login_logout and has parent matching: with id: logout:id/main_layout and is displayed on the screen to the user)
>
> If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following
>
> AdapterViews:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{3ca0fd9d GFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f10043a app:id/language_profile_edit}

```
ViewInteraction appCompatTextView5 = onView(
allOf(withId(R.id.Profile_login_logout),
withParent(withId(R.id.main_layout)),
isDisplayed()));
appCompatTextView5.perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

Here is the xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dull_gray">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_profile"
    style="?android:progressDrawable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_loading_profile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/progress_profile"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/loading"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_bg">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/person_image_profile_containner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/person_image_profile"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin20" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_image_profile"
                style="?android:progressDrawable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_image_profile_containner">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/person_name_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/person_name_profile_edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_name"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mobile_profile_initial"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSizeS"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/mobile_profile_edit_initial"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_profile_edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                
      <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                        android:text="@string/language"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/language_profile_edit"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/selected_exams"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/selected_exams"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/horiz_scroll_exams"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/personal_information"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                        android:text="@string/personal_information"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="@string/date_of_birth"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/qualification"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize16" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/qualification_profile_edit"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/topMargin"
                        android:padding="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize16"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Personal_address"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/address"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize16" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/address_basic"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edit_address_basic"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/topMarginU2"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMarginU1"
                            android:hint="@string/enter_address"
                            android:visibility="gone" />


                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/edit_address_state"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/topMargin"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txtSizeS"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/dull_gray" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dot1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/dot" />

                </RelativeLayout>



            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Profile_login_logout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/signup_splash_tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean, with "under a linear layout"? Is `TextView` a child of the `LinearLayout` or is the `TextView` behind the `LinearLayout` (using the same region on the screen)? Post your layout.

Comment: TextView is child of Linear layout

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: I can't find the view with Login_logout id in this xml. Should it be Profile_login_logout instead of Lofin_logout? Also, maybe you want to try isDescendantOfA instead of withParent if the main_layout it's not the direct parent of that TextView.

Comment: Thats my bad..sorry, Profile_login_logout is the correct id. While posting the question I had made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Given how humongous the layout is, I suspect that the `allOf()` matcher fails at `isDisplayed()`. Which fails when the view is not currently displayed on the screen.

I don't really see why you need all three matchers to uniquely identify the view. `Profile_login_logout` appears to be a unique ID  which doesn't require anything other than `withId()` matcher.

If you want to make an assertion that this view is displayed you need to scroll to it first. However `scrollTo()` will check if the view is displayed after scrolling as part of the `perform()` call.  Moreover `click()` has `isDisplayingAtLeast(90)` constrain baked in as well.

In case you are dealing with a ViewPager (which I hope is not the case) or something similar you can look for the view through its parent like this `allOf(withId(R.id.Profile_login_logout), hasParent(allOf(withId(R.id.main_layout), isDisplayed()))`

`onData()` is not needed for this test as you don't have any adapter views other than spinner which is not part of what are currently testing.

Comment: xml file was bit longer that's why I have removed some lines. This is the reason, layout was looking good. So how am I suppose to apply this solution to my code? , I am kind of new to this.

Comment: If my original assumption was correct and the reason for the failure is that the view is off the screen, then your ViewInteraction should look like: `withId(R.id.Profile_login_logout)` and that should work as it uniquely identifies the view in the layout that you posted.

Comment: `android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:` No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: logout:id/Profile_login_logout and is displayed on the screen to the user) This error is generated when I used this code: 
`ViewInteraction appCompatTextView5 = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.Profile_login_logout), isDisplayed()));
        appCompatTextView5.perform(scrollTo(), click());`

Comment: Well  you added `isDisplayed()` again to your matcher  that is a potential cause here. Could you try without it? Just `onView(withId(R.id.Profile_login_logout)`